# pgfkeys: Store unknown keys in a command

Tags: pgfkeys

Does `pgfkeys` have some some predefined handler to store unknown keys and their values in a command as a list? E.g. in the following example I would like to get a command which contains `blub=1, bla=\textbf{2}`. (I want to pass the unknown keys to `\includegraphics`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfqkeys{/my key}{
 x/.initial={0.5},
 .unknown/.code={\pgfkeyscurrentname=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/my key/.cd, x=2, blub=1, bla=\textbf{2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does there exist a pre-defined list of “unknown” keys that are allowed for storing in that list command? Other than that you might just add (expanded once) `\pgfkeyscurrentname` and `\pgfkeyscurrentvalue` to that list? Of course, any misspelled or *really* unknown key will be forwarded too.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I simply want to forward every unknown key to `\includegraphics`. If the list contains a key which `\includegraphics` doesn't know it should give the normal error messages. With xkeyval I would use `\XKV@rm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines?

The handler `.unknown to list` installs an `.unknown/.code` key that appends the unknown key and possibly its given value (enclosed in `{ }`) to the list `#1`. An additional `.@clear list` key is used to clear the list `#1`, though if the keys are executed inside a group (as with TikZ on paths) there shouldn’t be much use for it, I guess.

The `\pgfutil@gobble` (which apparently isn’t available with `pgfkeys`) removes the first `,` from the list. (Of course, is the solution is only intended for LaTeX, the usual `\@gobble` can be used anyway.)

The amount of `\expandafter`s simulates a `\expandonce`/`\appto` combo (`etoolbox`) because we can’t assume everything is expandable (and should be expanded at all).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfutil@gobble#1{}
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.unknown to list/.code=%
  \let#1\pgfutil@gobble
  \pgfkeysalso{% or \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.cd,
    .unknown/.code=% how to handle the difference between 'key' and 'key=value'?
      \ifx\pgfkeyscurrentvalue\pgfkeysnovalue
        \let\pgfkeys@temp\pgfkeyscurrentname
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfkeys@temp\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\pgfkeyscurrentname\expandafter=\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}%
      \fi
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter#1\expandafter,\pgfkeys@temp},%
     .@clear list/.code=\let#1\pgfutil@gobble}%
}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{/my key/.cd,
 x/.initial={0.5},
 .unknown to list=\myList
}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  /my key/.cd,
  x=2,
  blub=1,
  bla=\textbf{2},
  dingenskirchen=something else
}

\meaning\myList

\pgfkeys{/my key/.@clear list}

\meaning\myList
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This works and give the expected output. In the meantime I also found a solution using filtered keys but I don't like it (to much install filter and handlers involved). I think I will revert to my other idea: Giving the keys not known to includegraphics some default meaning.