# pgfopts .unknown does not handle key-value pairs?

Tags: package-writing, pgfkeys, documentclass-writing, class-options, pgfopts

I would like my custom class to forward unknown keys to the base class, or in this case, a package.

The following works (to make the example smaller, this forwards only one key; expanding it to a list would clutter the code):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2020/02/17 MWE]

\LoadClass{beamer}

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\def\@unknownkeys{}

\pgfkeys{
    /mwe/.cd,
    .unknown/.code={
        \message{mwe found unknown key: \pgfkeyscurrentname}
        \edef\@unknownkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentname}
    }
}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mwe}
\relax

\PassOptionsToPackage{\@unknownkeys}{geometry}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
```

Now the following document:

```
\documentclass[showframe]{mwe}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

displays a frame, as expected.

But if I modify my code by replacing

```
\edef\@unknownkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentname}
```

by

```
\edef\@unknownkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentname=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}
```

then it does not work anymore:

```
\documentclass[paper=a0paper]{mwe}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

gives me a DIN-A4 document. What's more, the custom message does not appear in the log, showing that the .unknown/.code was never executed at all.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I originally had code similar to that provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120055), but that does not work, as you can see above.

Edit: forgot a line in my MWE.

Comment: Welcome! On my machine not even your working example works. It does say `mwe found unknown key: showframe`, as you describe, but then terminates with the error `! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Thank you, of course. In my rush to minimize the MWE I deleted the \LoadClass line. The edited version works for me as described.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it is the class **beamer** which kills it. Moving the \LoadClass statement to after the option processing makes it work as expected.

My best guess is that beamer uses some .unknown handler internally itself. I would still be glad for a more qualified explanation though.